# JOIN cannot find the column on the corret table in scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have some models like this:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Teacher
  scope :rich_students, joins(:teachers).order('students.money DESC')
end
```

And then class Teacher

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
  belongs_to :Organization
end
```

And then:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teachers 
end
```

Now I write a query like this:

```
Student.rich_students.joins(:teachers).where("teachers.organization_id = ?", params[:id]).limit(5)
```

But this is NOT working. It gives me the error:

```
Association named 'teachers' was not found;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldnt the join be

Student.rich_students.joins(:teacher)

?

Comment: so when we use something in the joins(Blah),  that "blah" shouldn't be pluralized ? right?

Comment: That's generally correct.  You can play with this in the rails console to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an error in your Student "belongs_to" declaration it should be

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  scope :rich_students, joins(:teachers).order('students.money DESC')
end
```

":teacher" instead of ":Teacher"

Hope it can be the cause of matter...

Cheers